# Strange symbols instead of Cyrillic Django

Tags: python, django, encoding

I'm trying to add data to DB by external script.
In this script, I first create a list of `Model` elements, and then add them to DB by `bulk_create` method.

```
from shop.models import SpeciesOfWood

species_of_wood = [
    SpeciesOfWood(title="Ель"),
    SpeciesOfWood(title="Кедр"),
    SpeciesOfWood(title="Пихта"),
    SpeciesOfWood(title="Лиственница")
]
SpeciesOfWood.objects.bulk_create(species_of_wood)
```

This code works well in terms of **adding** data to DB, but idk what happens with **values** I wanted to add, here is screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

I already tried to add:

- `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`
- **u** prefix to `title` values

But it didn't change anything.

UPD 1

I tried to create models myself like `SpeciesOfWood.objects.create(...)` and it also doesn't change anything.

UPD 2

I tried to add cyrillic data via admin panel, and it works ok, data looks like I wanted. I still don't know why data added via script added with wrong encoding, but via admin panel ok.

UPD 3

I tried to use `SpeciesOfWood.objects.create(...)` via `python manage.py shell`, and it works well if I write it by hand. Also, it can be useful, I executing this dummy data script using this code:

```
>>> python manage.py shell
>>> exec(open("my_script.py").read())
```

Comment: The coding: utf-8 doesn't SET encoding, it just CLAIMS encoding. It's possible your editor isn't actually saving the file as unicode.

Comment: Python version?

Comment: @RemcoGerlich 3.8.1

Answer (score 0):

This looks suspiciously like your database is misconfigured, or the software with which you're reading the data back is: the characters in the table image corresponds to your original data encoded to UTF-8 then decoded to [Windows-1251](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1251) (a "legacy" cyrillic encoding although wikipedia tells me it remains extremely popular):

```py
>>> print("Ель".encode('utf-8').decode('windows-1251'))
Р•Р»СЊ
```

This means either the database is configured such that the reader assumes Windows-1251 encoding, or the software you use to view database content assumes the database returns data in whatever encoding is setup on the system (and your desktop environment is configured in cyrillic using windows-1251 / cp1251).

Either way it doesn't *look* like an issue with the *input* to me as the data is originally encoded / stored as UTF-8.

Comment: thx for answer. What if I don't touched db? By default Django uses SQLite. Also I have read that this db uses UTF-8 as default encoding. What can I do in that case?

Answer (score 0):

Answer lies in the way how I executing script. [The default encoding is platform dependent (whatever locale.getpreferredencoding() returns)...](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open). I was mistaken in thinking that default encoding while reading file is UTF-8.